# Parsing a certain string only separated with spaces in PHP

Tags: php, string, parsing

I have a string:

> Type Type1 IP 192.168.0.1 Authorized No AllowMultiple Yes

So this string has variables:
Type, IP, Authorized, and AllowMultiple

- Type's value is Type1
- IP's value is 192.168.0.1
- Authorized's value is No
- AllowMultiple's value is Yes

How do I parse just from that string format to get the values of each variable?

For example from that string above, how would I be able to say:

```
$type = value_from_string('Type', $str);
```

Comment: For clarification: is the string format stable, that is, is `Type` always the first component, or are you deriving the fact that `Type1` is the value of variable `Type` based on the fact that it comes after the substring `Type`, but the pair `Type Type1` could be, for example, at the end of the string?

Comment: The order of the string will always be the same. Type1 is just a coincidence that it has the word 'Type' in it.

But it's all good now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$s = "Type Type1 IP 192.168.0.1 Authorized No AllowMultiple Yes";

$s = explode(' ', $s);
$arr = [];
for($i=0;$i<count($s);$i+=2) $arr[$s[$i]] = $s[$i+1];

print_r($arr);
```

Gives us:

```
Array
(
    [Type] => Type1
    [IP] => 192.168.0.1
    [Authorized] => No
    [AllowMultiple] => Yes
)
```

You may want to add `extract($arr)` if you want plain variables like `$Type` instead.
The other way to achieve it would be to drop the array and create variables on the fly:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($s);$i+=2) $$s[$i] = $s[$i+1];
echo $Type;
echo $IP;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = explode(' ', 'Type Type1 IP 192.168.0.1 Authorized No AllowMultiple Yes');
```

Will give you an array with each of those pieces.  From there you can figure out how to create your `value_from_string` function.

Comment: I suppose I can just use every second multiple like how the first person did. Thanks for this.